# Check in code to tfs from external zip-file

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, team-explorer

I've been working on a bug lately on my mac computer. This is what I did:

I downloaded the zip-file from tfs to my mac and fixed the bug. I ziped the file and got it over to my windows comp. What I wanna do now is to check in code from that zip file to the branch where I got the code from.

Im connected to the team on tfs but I cant see any changes in the team explorer while having the project in VS 17 and connected to tfs through team explorer at the same time. I appreciate any help I can get or any directions at all! Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you download the zip file and check-in the changed zip file? Is the ziped file in source control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you can not simply downlaod the zip files from web portal.

1. Get(downlaod) the zip file in **workspace** which mapped to the
   specific branch.
2. Eextract the files --> change codes --> zip the files again. (You
   can do this in anywhere with windows explorer)
3. The most important thing is that you need to copy the new zipped file
   (with the same name) to the **workspace** to replace the old one, and you can see the
   pending changes, then check in the changes.

I tested that on my side and that works as expected.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you can not see the zip file in Source Control Explorer, then that means the zip file is not in source control. You need to add the file to source control.

1. Copy the zip file to workspace folder
2. Right-click in **Source Control Explorer** --> **Add items to
   Folder** --> Select the zip file in `Add to Source Control` dialog,
   then **Next**  --> **Finish**

   [image]

Comment: @petterandersson Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: I can't find the zip file. How do I search through out my comp? @Andy Li-MSFT

Comment: @petterandersson What's that mean for "I can't find the zip file"? Do you mean that you can not see the zip file in Source Control Explorer?  See my updated answer.

Comment: The zip file is on my desktop but it doesnt show on pending files. @Andy Li-MSFT

Comment: @petterandersson If the file is not in workspace folder and not in source control, then you will not see the files in pending changes. Just Copy and Paste to the workspace folder. Then follow the steps mentioned in above answer.

Comment: @petterandersson You need to Connect to TFS and create a workspace  to map the sources to a local folder, then edit the files in this local folder. See [Connect from Visual Studio or Team Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/user-guide/connect-team-projects#connect-from-visual-studio-or-team-explorer) for details.